# python scrapy Xpath selecting text() not getting

Tags: xpath

I have this HTML code:

```
<div class="copy" style="padding:0px 45px 15px 30px;"><img src="/images/dot_clear.gif" height="1" width="623" border="0" class="">

        <span class="copybold">
            <span class="">viswa</span>
        </span>
        <div class="">

            <span class="">first value</span><br class="">
            <span class="">100-100-1000</span><br class="">
            <span class="">2304 street</span><br class="">
            <span class="">kannamapet</span>,&nbsp;
            <span class="">TN</span>&nbsp;
            <span class="">6000002</span><br class="">

        </div>

        Lic. Num:<span class="">234</span><br class="">
        Lic. Year:<span class="">01/01/2001</span><br class="">
        Lic. Expiration Year:<span class="">12/31/19</span><br class="">
        Certificate approved . 
        <span class="copybold">
            <span class="">Nathan</span>
        </span>
        <div class="">

            <span class="">second value</span><br class="">
            <span class="">200-200-2000</span><br class="">
            <span class="">2367 street</span><br class="">
            <span class="">kannamapet</span>,&nbsp;
            <span class="">TN</span>&nbsp;
            <span class="">6000002</span><br class="">

        </div>

        Lic. Num:<span class="">235</span><br class="">
        Lic. Year:<span class="">01/01/2002</span><br class="">
        Lic. Expiration Year:<span class="">12/31/2012</span><br class="">
        Certificate approved .
```

I'm trying to get Lic. Num value = 234 and 235 and lic year but always showing null or invalid xpath,

I tried with:

```
//*[contains(text(), 'Num')]
```

But this is returning null.

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: Can you update the question if you are using _Selenium_ and which Selenium client java/Python?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following xpath.

```
//span[@class='copybold']/following-sibling::span[1]
```

**Snapshot**:

[image: Snapshot]

Comment: Sorry I'm using python scrapy. if more num is there then how can i get.

Comment: Try this xpath : `//div[@class='copy'][contains(.,'Num')]/span[2]`

Comment: Sorry I don't know scrapy.However I believe above xpath should work.

Answer (score 0):

To get `234`

```
//div[@class='copy']/div[@class=''][1]/following-sibling::span[@class=''][1]/text()
```

To get `235`

```
//div[@class='copy']/div[@class=''][2]/following-sibling::span[@class=''][1]/text()
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the license numbers:

```
//span[@class=''][preceding::text()[1][contains(.,'Lic. Num')]]/text()
```

Output:

> 234
>
> 235

To get the licence years:

```
//span[@class=''][preceding::text()[1][contains(.,'Lic. Year')]]/text()
```

Output:

> 01/01/2001
>
> 01/01/2002